# Find last several dates by customer

Tags: sql, max

The table I have is customer, customerid, cost, date
I want to find the last 4 dates for EACH customer, so that I can eventually aggregate over these dates. Not all customers have the same dates. The rows (and therefore dates) are missing for some customers whose cost is 0.

```
Customer  ID   Cost   Date

Alfred    1    100    7/1
Alfred    1    100    7/2
Alfred    1    200    7/3
Alfred    1    300    7/5
Alfred    1    200    7/6
Bob       2    500    7/4
Bob       2    500    7/5
Bob       2    500    7/6
Bob       2    500    7/7
```

etc. So for Alfred, I want to pull the rows for dates 7/2, 3, 5, & 6. For Bob I want to pull all his rows. If a customer has less than 4 dates/rows, I don't want any of their rows (though this can be done separately - not the big issue). Only pulling the rows of the last 4 dates of each customer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most dialects of SQL support the `dense_rank()` window function.  This is exactly what you need for this problem:

```
select t.Customer, t.ID, t.Cost, t.Date
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by Customer order by "Date" desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 4;
```

`Dense_rank()` handles duplicates by including all rows from most recent four dates in the data.  If you want exactly four rows from the most recent dates, then use `row_number()` instead.